# printf statement in color

Tags: c, gcc, printf

CODE

```
char *pcs = "\e[1;34m%d\e[0m";
int main()
{
    printf(pcs,12313213);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

12313213 in blue

I want to `printf` 2 number in blue. something like --->

```
printf(pcs+pcs,12313213,999); //(does not work)
```

Can someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement
pcs+pcs adds two pointers. The result is a pointer that points somewhere completely unrelated which will almost certainly crash your program.
The right way to do what you want is to either change the format string to accept two numbers:

```
char *pcs = "\e[1;34m%d%d\e[0m";
```

or make the format string a macro and use it two times:

```
#define pcs "\e[1;34m%d\e[0m"
printf(pcs pcs,12313213,999);
```

Note that there is no comma between the two macro instantiations.

Comment: I did try this but wasnt working. Now when i try this again , it works. 
"GHOST CODE"

Answer (score 2):

`pcs` is a pointer... with `pcs+pcs` you double the address... you can call twice `printf`:

```
printf(pcs,12313213);
printf(pcs,999);
```

You can also split the color changing pattern in a mask:

```
char *COLOR = "\e[1;34m";
char *ENDN = "\e[0m";
int main()
{
   printf("%s%d%s %s%d%s", COLOR, 12313213, ENDN, COLOR, 999, ENDN);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to do in a single `printf` statement. Is it possible??

Comment: A colorprintf function would be nice: cprintf(color, mask, params...)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more `%d` in the value of  `pcs` i.e. `char *pcs = "\e[1;34m%d %d\e[0m";`

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
printf("\e[1;34m%d\e[0m \e[1;34m%d\e[0m",12313213,999);
```